# How can i enforce the scaffolding automatically generated code to display the Label and the EditorFor text field at the same line in my asp.net mvc 3

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, razor

I am developing an asp.net mvc 3 with razor view , i also automatically generate the associated action methods and view using the scaffolding template.
But the problem i am facing is that on the view the `lable` and `editorfor` input field will be displayed in two separate lines (each on a separate `Div`)as follow:-

```
<div class="editor-label">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.FirstName)
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.FirstName)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.FirstName)
        </div>
```

So is there a way to do a change to force the label and the input input box to be displayed beside each other ,, without the need to manually modify the code at each view ?
BR

Comment: You need to look at your CSS, by default they are on the same line.

Comment: thanks for the reply; but no by default they are on a seperate lines..

Comment: Every new MVC project I make always has the label on the same line; I don't think yours is different.

Comment: no what i mean that the default mvc will display the label and the related text field in two seperate lines ,,, but i need to display the related label and field at the same line... BR

Answer (score 2):

You can edit the t4 templates that output the markup directly.  The scaffolding files can be found on your machine here:

C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\Common7\IDE\ItemTemplates\CSharp\Web\MVC 3\CodeTemplates\AddView\CSHTML

You will see a list of .tt files, and these are the files that are used to generate the automatically-outputted html.  If you don't the like default way that the elements are layed out, change them!  Just remember, changing these will result in a permanent change to the scaffold.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if this is what you are looking for but here is my view:

```
    <div class="editor-label">
    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Title)
    </div>
    <div class="editor-field">
    @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Title)
    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Title)
    </div>

    <div class="editor-label">
    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.DateCreated)
    </div>
    <div class="editor-field">
    @Html.EditorFor(model => model.DateCreated)
    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.DateCreated)
    </div>
```

And I modified this CSS to add float: left; to each of the classes

```
.display-label, 
.editor-label {
margin: 1em 0 0 0;
float: left;
}

.display-field, 
.editor-field {
margin: 0.5em 0 0 0;
float: left;
}
```

Comment: thanks for the reply, the above will display all the label and fields beside each others,, but what i am trying to do is to only display the related label and field at the same line, then for the second label and field to add them in a seperate line and so on...

Answer (score 0):

In the default `Site.css` file that's created by Visual Studio (so `\Your Project\Content\Site.css`), under the `/* forms */` section, you'll see the following:

```
label {
    display: block;
    font-size: 1.2em;
    font-weight: 600;
}
```

Just change `display: block;` to `display: inline;`, and now all of your input fields will appear on the same line as the label.