# DataAnnotations on Entity not displaying in View

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

I have a Supplier Entitiy that contains

```
ID - int
Status - string
Name - string
CreateDate- datetime
```

I am using the partial class method to create Data Annotations for the above Entity.as described [here](http://ryanhayes.net/blog/data-annotations-for-entity-framework-4-entities-as-an-mvc-model/)

```
namespace TemplateEx.Models
{
    [MetadataType(typeof(SupplierMetadata))]
    public partial class Supplier
    {
        // Note this class has nothing in it.  It's just here to add the class-level attribute.
    }

    public class SupplierMetadata
    {
        // Name the field the same as EF named the property - "FirstName" for example.
        // Also, the type needs to match.  Basically just redeclare it.
        // Note that this is a field.  I think it can be a property too, but fields definitely should work.

        [Required]
        [Display(Name = "Supplier Name")]
        public string Name;
    }
}
```

My defined a controller action as below

```
 public ViewResult Details(int id)
    {
        Supplier supplier = db.Suppliers1.Single(s => s.ID == id);
        return View(supplier);
    }
```

When I create a view for this action and picked the Details scaffolding for the Supplier entity following is what I got as a view

```
@model TemplateEx.Models.Supplier

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Details";
}

<h2>Details</h2>

<fieldset>
    <legend>Supplier</legend>

    <div class="display-label">CreateDate</div>
    <div class="display-field">
        @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.CreateDate)
    </div>

    <div class="display-label">Status</div>
    <div class="display-field">
        @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.Status)
    </div>

    <div class="display-label">Name</div>
    <div class="display-field">
        @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.Name)
    </div>
</fieldset>
<p>
    @Html.ActionLink("Edit", "Edit", new { id=Model.ID }) |
    @Html.ActionLink("Back to List", "Index")
</p>
```

Notice how the model.Name has a "Name" label instead of "Supplier Name".What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You have the label hard-coded...

Comment: `SupplierMetadata.Name` should be a property, not a field.

Comment: Thanks Raphael Althaus. Is there a way where I can stop the scaffold ed view from hard coding the fields and instead use the <div class="display-label">@Html.LabelFor(model => model.Name)</div> or will I need to use a Template to do so

Answer (score 3, accepted):

replace

```
<div class="display-label">Name</div>
```

with

```
<div class="display-label">@Html.LabelFor(model => model.Name)</div>
```

Edit :

For the second question, look here
[How can i enforce the scaffolding automatically generated code to display the Label and the EditorFor text field at the same line in my asp.net mvc 3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10298986/how-can-i-enforce-the-scaffolding-automatically-generated-code-to-display-the-la) (specially last answer)